Studio Code cannot set active breakpoint on cpp file line but I can debug step by step?
I use VSCode to debug a project with C & C++ files all compiled in debug (-g)
On C files no problem to debug step by step or to put breakpoints.
On C++ I can debug step by step or line by line with watching datas but breakpoints appears always disabled, what I missed ?
I try to change file order in link tu put cpp at top of link,
but nothing change.

My guess is your c++ source file was not saved. Depending on your settings VSCode may not save your file before a compile or debug meaning it compiles the on disk version of your code and not the version in the editor.

if the file was not saved why when  I enter in cpp step by step I see the lines a I can watch any datas ?

See if there is a white dot next to the file name on the tab. If its white the file is not saved.

sorry, no white dot  next to file name on the tab

I use gcc 7.3.0, Gdb 8.2 (Ubuntu), Studio Code 1.84.1

You probably need to make a [mcve] for anyone to help. You may want to start with a hello world application and see if you can set breakpoint on that.
